# How to clone a XmlNodeList but replace name attribute of XmlNodes?

Tags: xml, sharepoint, xmlnodelist

How can I create an exact copy of a `XmlNodeList` but replace a part of all Attribute-Names of the XmlNodes?

What Im trying to do is to remove the `"ows_"` from the Attributes of the XmlNodes returned when calling `GetListItems` on a SharePoint WebService..

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.clone.aspx

the link deals with the `XmlNode.Clone()` method;
you could use that method to clone all the nodes (one-by-one) in the list then change them.